# trying to integrate CSV to Datatable jquery into wordpress plugin but facing with below issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, csv

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-CSV-File-Into-Data-Table.html
Even if i pass correct csv format in the csv file i am having errors

```
Uncaught Error: CSVDataError: Illegal Quote [Row:3][Col:1]
(anonymous function) @ jquery.csv.min.js?ver=4.2.3:25
$.csv.parsers.parse @ jquery.csv.min.js?ver=4.2.3:12
$.csv.toArrays @ jquery.csv.min.js?ver=4.2.3:63
(anonymous function) @ csv_to_html_table.js?ver=4.2.3:15
(anonymous function) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.2.3:2m.Callbacks.j @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.2.3:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.2.3:2x @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.2.3:4m.ajaxTransport.send.b @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.2.3:4
```

Here is the code which went into wordpress plugin
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_csvtable' );

```
function register_my_csvtable(){
    $my_page=add_menu_page( 'Basic Information From Quote Page', 'Quote Page CSV', 'manage_options', 'quotepage', 'quote_csv', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/csv-icon.png' ), 81); 
      add_action( 'load-' . $my_page, 'load_admin_files' );
    }


    function load_admin_files(){


        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_js' );

    }

    function enqueue_admin_js(){
       wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/css/bootstrap.css') );
         wp_enqueue_style( 'datatable180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css') );
         wp_enqueue_style( 'custom180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/css/custom.css') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/js/bootstrap.js') , array( 'jquery' ) );     
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjscsv180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/js/jquery.csv.min.js') , array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjqdt180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') , array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'datatablejs180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js') , array( 'jquery','bootstrapjs180') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'csv2htmljs180', plugins_url( 'csv2table180/script/js/csv_to_html_table.js') , array( 'jquery','bootstrapjs180' ) );

    }
```

function quote_csv(){

```
include_once(plugins_url('csv2table180/table.php'));
```

}

//In table.php my code is

init_table({
      csv_path: '',
      element: 'table-container',

    });

Comment: this doesn't help us to understand the issue!! You need to post actual line of code that's causing the issue!!\

Comment: Post a data sample. The parser is throwing an error because the data is malformed. Specifically line 3.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you try to load CSV file in the table via Javascript (frontend), and it seems by the error message that the error it faces is an "illegal quote" on first column of third row, which means that JS can't parse the CSV file correctly with the given delimiter and quotation rules.
You can take a deeper look into it, but I am not sure if this is the way to go, especially with larger files.
You may want to check this free WordPress table plugin that utilizes loading CSV files into jQuery DataTables: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpdatatables/

Comment: jquery-csv author here. You're absolutely right. Garbage-in-garbage-out. If the parser gets stuck it's because the data is malformed. According to the error, the cause of the issue is on line 3 of the CSV data file.